# mysql_query how to display html for if condition

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, if-statement

So I have this rustic and basic php that will check a value in my database and if its corrects it will pull out the rest of that row I guess but my problem is how to echo certaine html if the result is okay and how to echo some other html if else.

btw atm else is not working, in other words if you input a code that is not on my db it will not show anything

```
<?php
$db_hostname = 'localhost';
$db_database = 'codedb';
$db_username = 'root';
$db_password = '';
$table = 'users';
$field = 'code';
$test = 'first_name';


// Connect to server.
$connection = mysql_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password) OR DIE ("Unable to 
connect to database! Please try again later.");

// Select the database.
mysql_select_db($db_database)
    or die("Unable to select database: " . mysql_error());

$query = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE $field = '{$_GET["qcode"]}'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if ($result) {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                $name = $row["$field"];
                $test = $row["$test"];
                echo "Hello: $name $test";
            }
    }
    else {
        echo "Im sorry you buddy, you are not a winner this time! $test";
    }
   mysql_close($connection);
?>
```

Comment: just so you're aware, the script is open to sql injection, and mysql_* functions are obsolete in newer version of php :)

Comment: You REALLY want to move to PDO and prepared statements...But that is beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: thanks I wasnt aware of the injection but I was hoping for something like that since im just starting to code and yup I know that thanks tho

Comment: I personally like Zend Frameworks DB engine or ADODB (though it's really out dated now). But there are dozens of different frameworks out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) { echo "output"; } else { echo "error msg"; }
```

Comment: this worked, but I still dont know how to echo a full page for the different results

Comment: I get it but I tried to input a whole body and it did not work

Answer (score 1):

You can use [mysql_num_rows()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php), it's the best way.

```
if( mysql_num_rows($result) > 0 ){
/* Anything you want here on success */
} else {
/* Anything you want here on failure */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use mysql_num_rows against the query.

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result)){ } else { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of echoing every html value you can simply enclose html in if statements

like:

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE $field = '{$_GET["qcode"]}'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if ($result) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $name = $row["$field"];
            $test = $row["$test"];
?>
<b>Hello: <?php echo $name $test"; ?></b>
<?php
        }
}
else {
?>
    <b> Im sorry you buddy, you are not a winner this time! </b> <?php echo $test"; 
}
mysql_close($connection);
?>
```

Comment: Yep, you could because mysql_result returns false on failure.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to correct syntax of database selection like this

```
mysql_select_db($db_database,$connection);
```

Insted of

```
mysql_select_db($db_database);
```

Check [Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php)